# Discord bot clear command error [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object

Tags: javascript, error-handling, bots, discord, discord.js

When I or some random user try to use the !clear command I see this message in my channel.

"Yeah... That's not a number? I also can't delete 0 messages by the way.
Something went wrong... " + this error message.
`TypeError [MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE]: The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.`

In my console I get this error msg:
`(node:28184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.`

this is my clear.js script:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


    if (message.deletetable) {
        message.delete(); 
    }

    // Member doesn't have permission
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        message.channel.send("You can't delete messages...").then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    // Check if args[0] is a number
    if (isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <= 0) {
        message.channel.send("Yeah... That's not a number? I also can't delete 0 messages by the way.").then(m => m.delete(5000));

    }

    // Maybe the bot can't delete messages
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        message.channel.send("Sorry... I can't delete messages.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    let deleteAmount;

    if (parseInt(args[0]) > 100) {
        deleteAmount = 100;
    } else {
        deleteAmount = parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true)
        .then(deleted => message.channel.send(`I deleted \`${deleted.size}\` messages.`))
        .catch(err => message.channel.send(`Something went wrong... ${err}`));
}   


module.exports.help = {
  name: "clear"
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You must return when one condition is not true.
For the command works you must give a number of messages to clear: `!clear <Number>`.

```
    //...

    // Member doesn't have permission
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return message.channel.send("You can't delete messages...").then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    // Check if args[0] is a number
    if (isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <= 0) {
        return message.channel.send("Yeah... That's not a number? I also can't delete 0 messages by the way.").then(m => m.delete(5000));

    }

    // Maybe the bot can't delete messages
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return message.channel.send("Sorry... I can't delete messages.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
    }

    //...
```

You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return
Hope this help !

Comment: Hi Rakox, the return works, thanks!
Only my console keeps getting a error `node:14532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.` I get this error when I use `!clear`      or   `!clear 0`

Comment: When I comment this OUT on the 3 lines.
`//.then(m => m.delete(5000));`
Then I don't get the console error.
I don't know if this is the correct way.